# The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads

Tags: media

Not a folder permission issue. My website is evilsoulstudios.com. I am trying to upload an image using the "Upload New Media" with-in WordPress.

I am all of a sudden getting an error "The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads."

I have uploaded images the same way, a thousand times. I can use an FTP program to upload files to the same folder with no issues. I have full permissions to the "uploads" folder. I have not updated or installed anything new.  The only error I could find was:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in G:PleskVhostsevilsoulstudios.comhttpdocswp-contentpluginswoocommerceincludesabstractsabstract-wc-product.php on line 840

I've been searching for the issue for days with no solution. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you go to the media library, instead of using the drag and drop uploader, use the simple uploader instead so no javascript is involved, it will be easier to debug. Otherwise this could be anything, and you have no way of knowing why the AJAX upload request failed. All we know at this point is that it failed but we don't know why. Perhaps it couldn't create a new folder for this month? Or the file permissions are set correctly, but the ownership is incorrect? What happened that triggered this? These things don't just happen out of the blue, there'll be a change, update, etc

Comment: It could even be that you uploaded a very big file and ran out of disk space! Anything you can do to narrow down and simplify would be  helpful. Also how do you know it isn't a permissions issue? You stated it in your Q but you never explained how you confirmed this. That would be  valuable information that could eliminate or reveal other related issues

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was using the simple uploader for one image 952kb in size. I don't have "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders" option checked. I confirmed that my user account has administration rights to the "uploads" folder and the administrations rights are full access by going to my web host provider, right clicked on the "uploads" folder, and verified I had all access. How would I check ownership ? I created the account and installed/setup everything with the same user account.

Comment: You would have to check with your hosts documentation and tools for which user/group owns the folder. Permissions isn't as simple as setting the correct number. For example 664 says that the owner and the owners group can read and execute, but everybody else can only read. If your servers PHP is running as a user that isn't in that group then it can only read. That's why sometimes people use the exact permission number that the .org codex suggests, and it still doesn't work